# the design of kernel function and integral transform

Tags: integral-transforms, interpolation, kernels, integral-kernel

I read a solution of an integral inequality.
The solution uses condition $$f(1)=f(0)=f'(0)=0$$ to derive that
$$f(x)=\int_0^1k(x,y)f'''(y)dy$$, $$k(x,y)=\begin{cases}-\frac{x^2(1-y)}{2} & x\leq y\leq 1\\\frac{1}{2}(1-x^2)y^2+(x^2-x)y & 0\leq y<x\end{cases} $$

It seems that it designs a kernel to deal with the problem.

However, I cannot recognize what technique it applied to construct this kernel.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Write $2f(x)= x^2f''(0)+\int_0^x (x-t)^2 f'''(t)\, dt$ and use $f(1)=0$ to eliminate $f''(0)$.